# Where can I find a Ubuntu 14.04 video driver for the Dell ATI 128MB Radeon x300 se card?

Tags: ati, video, dell

I tried Dell's official support site and the option box listed for the Ubuntu OS was greyed out. I know this is a legacy card.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can't. The card is too old, and is only supported by the free radeon driver.

Comment: On the other hand, for old cards often the open source radeon driver is not a bad option. Anyone checked that one?